# Fedena - NoMethodError

Tags: fedena

> NoMethodError in FinanceController#fee_collection_create
>
> undefined method `bash' for localhost:D:/D:/Fedena:Rush::File
>
> D:/Fedena/vendor/plugins/delayed_job/lib/delayed/manager/local.rb:12:in
>   `scale_up'
>   D:/Fedena/vendor/plugins/delayed_job/lib/delayed/manager.rb:20:in`
>   send'
>   D:/Fedena/vendor/plugins/delayed_job/lib/delayed/manager.rb:20:in
>   `method_missing'
>   D:/Fedena/vendor/plugins/delayed_job/lib/delayed/job.rb:273:in`
>   after_create'
>   C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:347:in
>   `send'
>   C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:347:in`
>   callback'
>   C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:267:in
>   `create'
>   C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/base.rb:2874:in`
>   create_or_update_without_callbacks'
>   C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:250:in
>   `create_or_update'
>   C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/base.rb:2538:in`
>   save_without_validation'
>   C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/validations.rb:1078:in
>   `save_without_dirty'
>   C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/dirty.rb:79:in`
>   save_without_transactions'
>   C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:229:in
>   `send'
>   C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:229:in`
>   with_transaction_returning_status'
>   C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:136:in
>   `transaction'
>   C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:182:in`
>   transaction'
>   C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:228:in
>   `with_transaction_returning_status'
>   C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:196:in`
>   save'
>   C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in
>   `rollback_active_record_state!'
>   C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:196:in`
>   save'
>   C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/base.rb:723:in
>   `create'
>   D:/Fedena/vendor/plugins/delayed_job/lib/delayed/job.rb:126:in`
>   enqueue' D:/Fedena/app/controllers/finance_controller.rb:1224:in
>   `fee_collection_create'
>   D:/Fedena/app/controllers/finance_controller.rb:1194:in`each'
>   D:/Fedena/app/controllers/finance_controller.rb:1194:in
>   `fee_collection_create'
>
> Request
>
> Parameters:
>
> {"authenticity_token"=>"Nd/L3pku0/+YQa6buSQ9x4lWSDl8ASJFEdYRY9KmSEA=",
>   "finance_fee_collection"=>{"end_date"=>"2015-09-19", 
>   "name"=>"Tuition",  "due_date"=>"2015-09-19", 
>   "fee_category_id"=>"School Fee",  "start_date"=>"2015-09-19"}, 
>   "commit"=>"► Create",  "fee_collection"=>{"category_ids"=>["3"]}}
>
> Show session dump Response
>
> Headers:
>
> {"Content-Type"=>"",  "Cache-Control"=>"no-cache"}

Answer (score 0):

Use rush version 0.6.7

```
gem install rush -v 0.6.7
```